# http.request vs http.createServer

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest

What is the difference between the request in this line of code:

```
http.createServer(function(request,response){. . .}
```

and request in

```
http.request()
```

Are both requests done to the server?

I am new to node.js and I am sorry if I sound dumb!

How does `http.request()` work?

In `http.request()` we fetch data from another site but in order to fetch data from another site we first need to go to our site and then make a request? Explain it with a simple real-life example!

Comment: where did you find http.request() ?

Comment: http.createServer used to create a server that can listen on specified port to http requests and send http responses

Comment: `createServer()` listens for incoming http connections from some other client.  `http.request()` sends an outbound http request to another server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http.request()` makes a request to another HTTP server.  Suppose for some reason I wanted to go download Stack Overflow's home page...

```
http.request('https://stackoverflow.com/', (res) => {
  // ...
});
```

`http.createServer()`... it creates an HTTP server.  That is, it binds your application to a socket to listen on.  When a new connection is made from somewhere or something else, it handles the underlying HTTP protocol of that request and asks your application to deal with it by way of a callback.  From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response):

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('okay');
});
```

These two methods have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  `http.request()` is for making a request to an HTTP server.  `http.createServer()` is for creating your own HTTP server.  Don't get confused by the callbacks.

Comment: can you explain the request and the response parameters in http.createServer(req,res)? what are these requests?

Comment: Requests from other HTTP clients to your server.  For example, if you opened up the URL to your Node.js server in your browser, with that example code you would see "okay" in the browser.  `req` is the request object, which can be inspected for what the path was and such.  `res` is the response object which you use to control what gets sent back.  I really recommend reading the documentation and trying the very first example within it:  https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html#synopsis_example

Comment: okay! by the usage of http.createServer one doesnt need to host their website on other servers like GoDaddy.com or AWS as they have created their own server?

Comment: @rohan You would need to host your Node.js application itself somewhere.  Really though, if all you want is static web hosting, you should use a server built for that such as Nginx.  The web server built into Node.js is better designed for API-style servers, where there might be an upstream proxy.  Think of the HTTP server in Node.js as a replacement for FastCGI.  You definitely *can* use it with clients directly, but if you start to get enormous amounts of traffic, it can help to use something downstream to balance load and handle terminating to clients.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the source code of nodejs (extract below), createServer is just a helper method to instantiate a Server.

Extract from line 1674 of [http.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1674).

```
exports.Server = Server;


exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
};
```

The `http.request()` API is for when you want your server code to act as a client and request content from another site and has `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` methods.